# How do I live-view all or a subselection of "when clause context" values?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The [docs for the "when clause contexts"](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#available-contexts) are OK, but for extension/keybinding debugging purposes I'd really like to see the current, dynamically updating values of these when clause contexts. Is there a way to (easily) see them?

Possibly related questions and Github issues:

- [A method to expose the VSCode active 'when Clause Contexts'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43372232/61109)
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/118722

Answer (score 1):

When the Developer Tools are open, there's the "Developer: Inspect Context Keys" command:

[image]

[Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#inspect-context-keys-utility)